# O que significa "@" em JSF?

Tags: jsf

O que significa este @ nas páginas JSF? Ex:

```
process="@this"
update="@form"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O @ em JSF é usado nas chamadas anotações, que servem para anotar classes, métodos e campos para que possam ser tratadas pelo compilador, ferramentas de desenvolvimento e bibliotecas. Existe explicação mais técnica pra isso, mas em simples palavras seria como se quando você rodasse o programa
ele verificasse essas anotações em tempo de compilação ou utilizasse-as por ferramentas, tais como analisadores de código, frameworks de persistência ou de testes unitários, entre outras.
Existem anotações marcadoras, anotações de valor único Ex. @Anotacao("valor"), Anotações completas, padrões como @Override da java.lang. Ex. a anotação @Deprecated é uma anotação marcadora que indica que um método está obsoleto e é colocada na assinatura do método. @SuppressWarnings desliga os alertas de uma parte do codigo da aplicação, e outras.

Comment: Eu me refiro aos "@" nas páginas xhtml, não nas classes java.

Comment: Entendi, desculpe o mal entendido. Não sei se estou 100% certo mas por ex. quando numa tag <h:commandButton> no atributo update eu atribuir @form (update="@form''), ele atualiza a página inteira ao clicar no botão, evitando erros pois as vezes uma parte do código não é compilada e tal.. não sei se ajudou.